# Xen VM Machine performances Slow while second machines turn on

Tags: virtual-machines, xen

Actually If i try to access Second VM Machines at same time means getting performance issue,Even not able to access the application in the VM . 
I'm very new to this , So could n't find exact issue , Please guide me to solve the issue. thanks in advance.

Xl Info 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSfYW.jpg)

Xen Network[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX6Wy.jpg)

Xen VM Machines Resource Allocation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EssBN.jpg)

Xen Vm machines disk Performance:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2yTY.jpg)

Xen Top Results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phUBk.jpg)

Comment: you need to check the resources the allocated for the vms.

Comment: Yes , I allocated 2GB Ram and 20 GB Memory space to run one simple php appliation.

Comment: the number of cpus the allocated for vms? because in your xl info I seen free_cpus 0

Comment: i allocated two cpu per vm machines.